# Parameters for generating controllers in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When using the command:

```
rails generate controller home index
```

When generating a controller do we always have to have a view be generated? Also, can a controller and a view be generated on its own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not always have to generate the action. In your case, if you just wanted to generate an empty controller, you can have:

`rails generate controller home`

Alternatively, controllers and views can be generated manually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're are getting the scaffolding wrong. It should provide you a basic skeleton for beginning and in the later advances on your work, you will start creating it by yourself.
Every time you need to create something custom means you are advancing so scaffolding will stop fitting your needs.